# Why am I unable to run npm commands on Git Bash?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, git-bash

I changed `NodeJS` version using `nvm` and now when I'm trying to run any `npm` command it throws an error. Event `npm -v` doesn't work. Here's the error:

```
ERROR: npm v9.6.6 is known not to run on Node.js v10.16.2. 
This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.

ERROR:
C:\Users\bazha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\exit-handler.js:19
  const hasLoadedNpm = npm?.config.loaded
```

`npm` works perfectly on windows' terminal and I get no error. The reason I want to use Git Bash is for `rm`.

The version of `NodeJS` I'm trying to use here is `10.16.2`. I used `nvm use 10.16.2` to change the versions. The `npm` version that is installed with `10.16.2 nodejs` is `6.9.0`. `node -v` on windows' terminal is `10.16.2`
`node -v` on Git Bash is `10.16.2`
`npm -v` on windows' terminal is `6.9.0`
`npm -v` on Git Bash throws the error above

**How do I run `npm` commands on Git Bash?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message provides you the exact reason:

```
This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
```

There are three version specifications and at least one of them **must** be met:

## 1

`^14.17.0` covers **14.17.x** versions, where x >= 0

## 2

`^16.13.0` covers **16.13.x** versions, where x >= 0

## 3

`>=18.0.0` covers anything above or equal with **18.0.0**

## Your problem

`10.16.2` does not meet any of the criterias from **1**, **2** or **3**. The error message also gives you the solution:

> You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

Hence, your git bash is using a very old version of Node.js. You will need to upgrade this for your git bash.